# Replace all superscript digits with one `re.sub`

Tags: python, regex

Given a string with exponents like `^2` in it, I'd like to replace them with their unicode equivalents using Python.

This works:

```py
import re

content = "m^2 s^3"

content = re.sub(r"\^0", "\N{Superscript Zero}", content)
content = re.sub(r"\^1", "\N{Superscript One}", content)
content = re.sub(r"\^2", "\N{Superscript Two}", content)
content = re.sub(r"\^3", "\N{Superscript Three}", content)
content = re.sub(r"\^4", "\N{Superscript Four}", content)
content = re.sub(r"\^5", "\N{Superscript Five}", content)
content = re.sub(r"\^6", "\N{Superscript Six}", content)
content = re.sub(r"\^7", "\N{Superscript Seven}", content)
content = re.sub(r"\^8", "\N{Superscript Eight}", content)
content = re.sub(r"\^9", "\N{Superscript Nine}", content)

print(content)
```

but I feel this repetition (or loop equivalent) can't be too efficient. Is there a way to solve the problem with one `re.sub`?

Comment: What is supposed to happen with `m^10`?

Comment: Similarly; `m^-1`?

Comment: Don't care about those, leave as they are.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lambda for the replacement in re.sub.  This will allow you to use a dictionary or translation table to map the numbers to their superscript versions.

```
import re

toSuper = str.maketrans("0123456789","⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹")

content = "m^2 s^3 x^59"

content = re.sub(r"\^([0-9]+)",lambda m:m.group(1).translate(toSuper),content)

print(content)

m² s³ x⁵⁹
```